# Sorting across three columns in Excel

Tags: excel, sorting, excel-formula

I am trying to sort across three columns.  In Google Sheets, I can accomplish this in a straightforward way using a forumula such as this: =SORT(AA5:AC,1, False)

[image: Successful Sort in Sheets]

How do I accomplish the same result as show in the image with Excel?

Using identical formula from Google Sheets didn't work in Excel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Reference like `AA5:AC` doesn't work in Excel like in Google Sheets.
   You either need to use `AA5:AC10`, `AA:AC` or find a way to
   determine where your array ends.
2. 3rd parameter in GS takes `TRUE` or `FALSE`, while in Excel it is
   `1` or `-1`. While `TRUE` works in Excel, false will not work
   instead of `-1`.

So use formula:

```
=SORT(AA5:AC10,1,-1)
```

[image]

Also, in Excel you will get *0* instead of blank cell after sorting. To avoid this:

```
=SORT(IF(AA5:AC10="","",AA5:AC10),1,-1)
```

Result:

[image]